# What's a good free bug tracking system that integrates with Mercurial and/or bitbucket?

Tags: mercurial, bug-tracking, bitbucket

I am a lone developer working on many projects simultaneously, and keeping all these bugs in my head has become burdonsome. I've been using some "task" websites to manage my bugs for a while now, and it's been relatively sufficient. However, my current project just exploded in scope and now I need something way more robust. I currently use Mercurial and BitBucket for my version control and repo respectively, so I was hoping someone knew of something that integrated with those. At the very least, I'm looking for a free bug tracking system.

PS: aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86394/free-cheap-task-bug-management-software) but I couldn't find anything with HG integration.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe change to [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/tip/www/index.wiki)? It has everything and more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are a lone developer you can just sign up for FogBugz startup edition for free:
http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/StudentAndStartup.html

Comment: yeah, i just found this literally three seconds ago and have already made a mess in my pants. i've been using fbz for the past year and am super familiar with it. joyous day!

Comment: The best part is that Klin (their distributed version control) works with Mercurial, which you mentioned you use. so win win.

Comment: yah... maybe i don't need bitbucket after all!

Comment: You can't have public projects on Kiln, other than that Kiln is superior to bitbucket in almost every way.

Comment: @Lasse: Don't worry, public repos will be coming to Kiln very soon.

Answer (score 13):

What about bitbucket itself? ;-) It uses some issue manager integrated.

[image]

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+your+Bitbucket+Issue+Tracker

Comment: it doesn't have a bug tracking system, though :\

Comment: @Jason: join the `admin` of your project and check if "Enable issue tracking" is checked. http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Enabling+your+Bitbucket+Issue+Tracker

Answer (score 1):

I generally set up [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) which is free, and you can do Mercurial integration via an [extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugzillaExtension). I believe that extension should install with Mercurial by default, but I don't actively use it so I can't say for sure. I don't know of a way to integrate BitBucket and Bugzilla though.

Answer (score 0):

Try Dilif - https://dilif.com/

It has Github integration and says bitbucket integration is coming. Please note that it is a cloud service so you can't install on your own server. But it provides way to integrate with any website. It also provides filters and sprint dashboards too.